# Trick Mac into thinking it has an external display

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, screen

I have a weird issue with my MacBook Pro.
The screen flickers when NOT connected to an external display.
Read more about it on this thread: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251849352

Is there a way to trick Mac into thinking it has an external display connected so I don't have to physically connect my Mac to display to use it?

Answer (score 4):

There’s no good way to set this in software, but you can get dummy display plugs for a fraction of the cost and space of an actual display.

They connect to a display output & fool the computer into thinking it's really a display. They're usually used for headless servers, but there's no reason I can think of you couldn't use one for your "second monitor" situation.

They come is various forms, HDMI, DVI, DP, VGA etc. Google/eBay/Amazon etc can find lots of them. Search for Ghost display or headless display. Quality on these can vary widely so consider buying some spares if you are not buying from a vendor with a return policy that you like.

Random pic of many types, anonymised

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This should work.

Any idea/help what is causing this problem?
I have also observed there is no flickering when I run VLC on the screen. Basically, any app that uses GPU (like external monitor, vlc ) there is no flickering.

I can not take mac to an apple service center right now because of covid situation. Any  help is appreciated.

Comment: Check if you have warranty coverage at https://checkcoverage.apple.com It might be the cable, impossible to tell without hands-on.

Comment: Would this work to use remote management in clamshell mode without an external display? :D

Comment: @FabioMagarelli - I have no idea & I don't have a laptop to test on.